# need help on understanding classes and methods

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, 
                                              resultCode, data);
}
```

here is what i understand:
`onActivityResult` is a method with some parameters

but what does the `super.onActivityResult` method do ?

and i have no idea what this means: `Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult`

I tried to look through the oracle documentation, but it just got me more confused...

can you help me ?

Comment: Take a look at Android's documentation. The `super` keyword means that you're calling the method as it's implemented on your class' superclass. As for `Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, 
                                              resultCode, data);`, it's a chained method call. `Session` is a class, `getActiveSession` is a static method that returns a session object and `onActivityResult` is a method called on the object returned.

Comment: that's why I believe it is important to study java first before you start developing android apps, atleast the oops concepts !

Answer (score 0):

As the `onActivityResult()` overrides another method, the call to `super.onActivityResult()` means that the version of the method from the parent (extended) class will be called.

Finally, `Session.getActiveSession()` will return the active session which is also a member of the classes hierarchy, and invokes the same method using its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`super.onActivityResult()` invokes the method's implementation found within the super class. As for your second question, `getActiveSession()` is a static method within the `Session` class. This means you could invoke the method without creating an instance of the class.

Comment: the class this code is located in, extends activity. so if i understan you correctly, in the activity class, there is a method called onActivityResult, and that is the one which will be used ?